# Netwire mutually dependant wires

Tags: haskell, frp, arrows, netwire

To try out Netwire, I'm implementing Pong using the library. In the code I have a ball wire and a computer paddle wire, and since they depend on each other for some values I've been running into issues with infinite loops. Some pseudo-code to explain:

```
ball :: Wire () IO GameInput Ball
ball = (... define ball ...) . pcPaddle

pcPaddle :: Wire () IO GameInput Paddle
pcPaddle = (... define pcPaddle ...) . ball
```

The thing to notice is they take each other for inputs. I've tried to alleviate this by doing the following:

```
ball :: Wire () IO GameInput Ball
ball = ( ... ) . delay ( ... base paddle init ...) . pcPaddle
```

and other variations of using the `delay` function in these two wires, but I'm getting the `<<loop>>` runtime error regardless.

How do I initialize one of the wires so that this system can work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course 5 minutes later I find the magic combination that seems to work. What I did was I altered the inputs the wires took in to be

```
ball :: Wire () IO Paddle Ball
ball = ...

paddle :: Wire () IO Ball Paddle
paddle = ...
```

then when it came to creating my network of wires I did this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DoRec  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
system = proc g -> do
    rec b <- delay (... ball initial value ...) . ball -< p
        p <- paddle -< b

    returnA -< (b,p)
```

This acknowlegdes their dependency, and gives the paddle the dummy initial value for the ball on it's first pass.